# Save/Load/Edit TreeView from ms access

Tags: c#, ms-access, treeview

I'm using a Tree-view control in my C# Form and I would like to save/load/Edit the content of this control on MS-Access database. And of course I don't want to get limited by levels and such things.
How can I do this?

Comment: The existing windows treeview control is a bit pants. I found this full-VBA one much more stable, and it might help you with your problem... https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/treeview.asp

Comment: It's exactly what I'm looking for, but this is not a source that I can learn from :/

Comment: Why not? Install the tool and view its code.

Comment: oh sorry I just noticed that there is a source code, but it's on VBA :/